# value of variable is not accurately get by if condition in php

Tags: php

I am trying to check if the value of variable is equal to 0 but if condition is not working correctly. Please see the following code

```
    if(isset($_GET['empid']))
                {
                        $sql_query="SELECT accept leave_mgt WHERE empid=".$_GET['empid'];
                        $result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
                        if(isset($sql_query)) 
                        {   
                            $sql="UPDATE leave_mgt SET accept='1'where empid=".$_GET['empid'];
                            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                            if($result)
                            {
                                echo "test";
                            }   
                            else
                            {   
                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                            }   
                        }   
                        else
                        {
                            $sql="UPDATE leave_mgt SET accept='0'where empid=".$_GET['empid'];
                            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                            if($result)
                                echo "testing";
                            else
                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Line 16 is never empty couse its the string...

Comment: I cannot see any comparison to `0` in your code

Comment: That must be the easiest case scenario for SQL injection... never use $_GET directly in your queries... you must sanitize it first

Answer (score 0):

Line 16

```
if(sizeof($result_set->fetch_assoc()) < 1) {
```